# facebook mobile app install ads track the install routes

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk, installation, ads

Is there a way to know if my app was installed over the **facebook Mobile App install Ads** using the Facebook SDK ?
The publish install is called every time my app getting installed but I want to know if the app is being installed via the Facebook ads service.
Thank you.

Comment: Were you ever able to find out any information on this?

Comment: no i could not find any thing

Comment: For those who still look for an answer, the answer I gave here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17998470/ should be valid for this question as well.

Comment: @Alex Wasweißich : Are you around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be possible, I found this (http://ampush.com/facebook-mobile-app-install-ads-good-gets-better/):

**Tracking can come through integration of a Facebook or Third Party SDK:**

An application does not require a Facebook login option in order to be promoted using Mobile App Install Ads, but the app must first be registered with Facebook. In order to track installs at the ad level, developers must install the most recent Facebook Software Development Kit (3.0 or greater for iOS, and the latest SDK for Android) or work with a 3rd-party mobile measurement provider.