# How to find out which facebook mobile install ad was clicked after installing the promoted iOS app

Tags: ios, facebook, parameters, ads, deep-linking

When a user clicks on a facebook mobile install ad on ios an app store window pops up.

As answered here [What happens to an iOS deeplink when the app is not installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17957945/what-happens-to-an-ios-deeplink-when-the-app-is-not-installed) it's not possible to put any custom parameters to be an launch parameter on the first app launch.

Is there a way after the downloaded app was opened and the user logged in with facebook to get information about which ad he clicked befor? Because actually there is a connection between ad, itunes app id, and facebook app id, isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19769928/identify-users-that-registered-via-fb-mobile-install-ad) today. But from the information that I was able to find, that is (most likely) not possible.

Even if your app **requires** the user to register with Facebook and you therefore you have a FB user Id which could potentially be matched against.. Because Facebook gives you the total install counts only, but not a list of user Ids of FB users who clicked your ad, I really can't imagine how to get that info. Unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I think we can use this link to check the Activities done on the FB Ad's. 
https://www.facebook.com/ads/manager/