# Identify users that registered via FB mobile install ad

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads-api

We (the company I work for) run several Facebook mobile install ad campaigns. We integrated the FB iOS SDK with our iOS application. Based on this, Facebook gives us the total app installs in the ad campaign reports (those users that clicked on the ad, were redirected to the Apple App Store and finally installed the app). So far, so good.

Now, I was asked (by our CEO) whether there's a chance that we not only get the total amount of app installs per campaign, but rather flag all users in our DB if they registered via a (specific) FB app install ad campaign.

However, because
 - a) FB does not provide a list of FB user id's (which could be matched against user Ids from app registrations via FB) and
 - b) it's also possible to install our app and then register by email (rather than via FB)
I don't see how that should work.

Now my question is: Am I missing something? Anyone an idea how that should work out?

Comment: have you figured that out? i'm strugling with the same problem