# Facebook ad attribution report per-user

Tags: facebook, pixel, ads

My company launched several Facebook ads campaign to drive page likes. Once the campaigns have run for several days, Facebook was able to generate a report of the result of the campaign, showing the **number of users** that are reached by the campaign aggregated by various dimensions (gender, age, etc).

Given that FB is able to show such aggregate value, I imagine internally FB ads attribution already associated the FB accounts that were reached by said campaign. But no matter what kind of report I try to create, there seems to be no way to download this **list of individual accounts that were reached by a campaign**, either via API nor GUI.

Is there a way to get this list? Or is it deliberately made not possible due to some regulations or privacy policy?

Comment: We want to create a report to track the following: given a user X, he has been reached via campaigns C1, C2, C3, before eventually converting.

Comment: A similar question for mobile apps ad:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19769928/identify-users-that-registered-via-fb-mobile-install-ad?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Facebook deliberately made it this way. You can access the performance data as granular as the ad level, but no further than that. I think attribution solution companies that collaborate with FB have access to the user level information, so the data are definitely collected and stored.